# Add 2 rows with different names from multiple results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a very simple SQL -

```
SELECT      QUEUE,
            COUNT (QUEUE) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM        MY_TABLE
GROUP BY    QUEUE
```

Which results in 10 rows of data, for example -

```
First Queue    15  
Second Queue   23  
Third Queue    48  
Fourth Queue   12  
etc
```

What I need to do is add the result for First Queue to the result of Second Queue and then change the name of Second Queue to New Second Queue, so I should end up with -

```
New Second Queue   38  
Third Queue        48  
Fourth Queue       12  
etc
```

I've not been writing SQL for than long and have spent many hours trying to resolve this without success.

Comment: you should have an order by clause also.. as the order may not be same in the result set always

Comment: Please tel me the order , is it based on queue name or First,Second etc..?

Answer (score 1):

```
select queue,
       count(*) as total
from
  (
  select case queue
           when 'First Queue' then 'New Second Queue'
           when 'Second Queue' then 'New Second Queue'
           else queue
         end as queue
  from YourTable
  ) as Q
group by queue
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, I can't seem to get this to work.  It's certainly addressing the problem I have, as it looks for the result string.  Sorry, I'm probably being a bit thick here, but where do I include 'MY_TABLE' within the above?

Comment: @Francis I added `YourTable` to where you should add `MY_TABLE` :).

Comment: @Francis If this post answered your question, please click the check-mark on the left side of the answer to mark it as accepted.  This lets others know you have had your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with cte as(
SELECT      QUEUE,
            COUNT (QUEUE) AS 'TOTAL',
            ROW_NUMBER() over(order by QUEUE) as rownum
FROM        MY_TABLE
GROUP BY    QUEUE)
select 'New '+QUEUE [QUEUE],TOTAL+(select TOTAL from cte where rownum=1) [TOTAL]
 from cte where rownum=2
 union all
 select QUEUE,TOTAL from cte where rownum>2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but unfortunately I won't always get the same results back each time. For example, First Queue may not appear everytime or I might need to combine Sixth Queue and Seventh Queue, which may not appear on rows 6 and 7.

Comment: @Francis: That was my question in the comment field , .. is the QUEUE name is always like FIRST QUEUE, Second Queue etc.. ? or its just an example of Queue names?

Comment: Hi Joe, sorry I'm new to this forum and wasn't looking in the right place.  Mikael's solution has resolved this.  Many thanks for your help.